# Zooming and Panning in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, zooming, pan

How can I zoom and pan a `div` in `IE8`?

any javascript library which support zooming and panning in `ie8`

when i tried with tweenlite that look something like this
 **http://jsfiddle.net/jophine/FLt9X/5/**

It's working fine on all browsers except for `IE8`.

[image]

[image]